# How to trigger a snippet of jquery every single page of a web app

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I have faced the linguistic problems for my web app. I want to localize my site using  Resource.resx , I have finished it already by running a  snippet of jquery code recording all text of a page then it pushes to an array and posts to server using ajax . of course I can add to resource programmatically in the server . But the problem now is I dont want to do it each page to store the text then later i can translate .  **I want a solution that helps me run the application once and I could have all text of it .**

Here is the code js .it runs per web request

[image]

And here is the code run while js send ajax request to server 
[image]

It works well if I do request for each page , But i want a solution that i just only run the webapp once and it programmatically records all text of my web app .
thanks for reading !!!

Comment: Please explain more, why you record all text of page?

Comment: I think the request is for some code that you can run (in JS) on every page and JS will scrape the content from the page, translate with some sort of translation service and then persist the translated content so that i can be used in a Resouce File.  @Van Minh is looking for a shortcut to explicitly writing Resource files for each piece of content on the site.

Comment: yes that is , but I am not gonna use the translation service . I do it my self .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my self . as you see the script above . I added request urls to the response JSon into the block code running at the server if the ajax sends request . The success callback of ajax can then set window.location.href = theurls . it automatically run my whole web app when i start the application .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store information throughtout your application, then you can either look into **cookies** / **Sessions** / **Html 5 Data api**

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Global Application Variables:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["MyVariable"] = "Value";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();
```

And you can Access them....

```
string LicenseName = HttpContext.Application["MyVariable"] as string
```

However, the most ideal solution would be to store the Data Once into Session / Cookie etc (make call to DB) using a Static Class, and then use this Static Class's member throughout your User's Visit Session. You can't Have the Session Live forever, every new visit need to make at least one DB call (unless you want to use cookies).

Comment: thanks for your help but what i need not to store the data at client side .

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is the Global Application Variable. please my edit.

Comment: you really don't understand . but the problem was solved already .